# How To show Just one line of the csv from the user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a program that automates my finances, the code till now is pretty good but I`m stuck into an issue. I need to make an input and when the user set the date that he want to print out from the extract it must print the whole line, how do I do that?

This is the code til now

```
import tabula
from tabula import wrapper
import pandas as pd


class BankAccountReport():

    def __init__(self):
        self.IV_total_spent = 0.0
        self.IV_current_funds = 0.0
        self.IV_expenses = []
        self.IV_deposits = []
        self.IV_expense_filters= []

    def analyzePdf(self):
        pdf_file = "Document"
        pdf_password = "1043322000"
        df = wrapper.read_pdf("Document.pdf", pages= "all", output_format="csv")
        print(df)
        df.to_csv("output.csv")
        df = pd.read_csv("output.csv", usecols=['Data', "Saldo (R$)"])
        print(df)



a= BankAccountReport()
a.analyzePdf()
```

Comment: Since you already have the data in a df, you could simply take an input from the user and filter the df with it. For ex:
 `print(df[(df['date'] == input('please enter the date: '))])`

Comment: @Limbo when I put that it gives error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Projeto automacao financeira/pdf.py", line 31, in <module>
    a.analyzePdf()
  File "C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Projeto automacao financeira/pdf.py", line 25, in analyzePdf
    print(df[(df['date'] == inp)])
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another method to your class. Also there's no point using classes if you are not storing variables inside them.
Here is a minimal working example for what you want.

```
class BankAccountReport:
    def __init__(self, pdf_file):
        self.df = wrapper.read_pdf(pdf_file)
    def get_row_by_date(self):
        date = pd.to_datetime(input("Input date to filter"))
        print(self.df[self.df.date_column==date])
```

Replace `date_column` with whatever is the name of column that stores the date you want to filter on.

Use it like this:

```
report = BankAccountReport("Document.pdf")
report.get_row_by_date()
```

Needless to say, you'll need to modify this to suit your other requirements.

Comment: Like this ? class BankAccountReport:
  def __init__(self, pdf_file):
    self.df = wrapper.read_pdf(pdf_file)

  def get_row_by_date(self):
    date = pd.to_datetime(input("Input date to filter"))
    print(self.df[self.df.Data == date])

report = BankAccountReport("Document.pdf")
report.get_row_by_date()

Comment: I still can`t search for the date. It gives me error when I put like 07/10/2019

Comment: That's because `pd.to_datetime` can only parse dates in so many formats. For your usecase, use the format argument like so:

`pd.to_datetime(input("Input date to filter"), format="%d/%m/%Y")`
Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Btw, it is always a good idea to check the documentation of the library in such cases. More often than not, if it is a popular library, docs tend to be extremely helpful.